# PHP DomXPath - "object value omitted" even if new DomDocument is not empty?

Tags: domxpath

I have a xml file like this...

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database xmlns="tt:foo" xmlns:h4a="https://www.myexample.com/foo.xsd" >
    <tables>
        <table name="my_first_table_name">
            <column name="column_name_1" />
        </table>
    </tables>    
</database>
```

I 'm trying to use `DOMXPath` for a future xml merging.

**PHP Code**

```
$doc_ref = new \DOMDocument();
$doc_ref->load( $array_xml_paths[0] );
$xpath_ref = new \DOMXPath($doc_ref);
error_log_array( $xpath_ref );
foreach ($xpath_ref->evaluate('//table[@name]') as $table) {
    $table_name = $table->getAttribute('name');
    error_log( $table_name );
}
```

**output**

```
[08-Mar-2018 14:21:47 UTC] DOMXPath Object

(

    [document] => (object value omitted)

)
```

The `DOMDocument` is correclty loaded, but something more seems to be necessary for `DOMXPath` to work it but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all...

> `[document] => (object value omitted)` DOES NOT MEAN the DOMXPath instance is empty !

I found the solution. It was in [this comment](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/class.domxpath.php#121043).

> I had to register the xml namespace to use `evaluate()`.

**Solution**

```
$doc_ref = new \DOMDocument();
$doc_ref->load( $array_xml_paths[0] );
$xpath_ref = new \DOMXPath( $doc_ref );
$ns = $doc_ref->documentElement->namespaceURI;
if($ns) {
    $xpath_ref->registerNamespace("ns", $ns);
    foreach ($xpath_ref->evaluate('//ns:table[@name]') as $table) {
        $table_name = $table->getAttribute('name');
        error_log( $table_name );
    }
}else {
    foreach ($xpath_ref->evaluate('//table[@name]') as $table) {
        $table_name = $table->getAttribute('name');
        error_log( $table_name );
    }
}
```